# Markers with circle, validate them with my positioning in android studio

Tags: android

**Hello, I am developing an app with android studio where I have some markers with circles, I want when my position is within some circle show the title of the marker.
This is the problem is that only validate the last marker
How can I get all markers validated?

```
enter code here

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



    markerCoords.add(POINTA);
    markerCoords.add(POINTB);
    nombres.add("punto 1");
    nombres.add("punto 2");

    for (int i=0; i<POINTS; i++)
    {
        drawMarker(new LatLng(markerCoords.get(i).latitude,markerCoords.get(i).longitude),nombres.get(i));
        double radiusInMeters = 5.0;
        int strokeColor = 0xffff0000;
        int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000;

        LatLng pos = markerCoords.get(i);
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(pos).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
        mCircle=mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(pos);
        mMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        allCircle.add(mCircle);
    }


        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            float[] distance = new float[2];

            for (int l=0; l<POINTS; l++)
            {
                Circle c = allCircle.get(l);
                Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),c.getCenter().latitude,c.getCenter().longitude,distance);
                if (distance[0]< mCircle.getRadius())
                {
                    String dato = allMarkers.get(l).getTitle();
                    tv.setText(dato);
                }
                else
                {
                    tv.setText("aqui");
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Do you mean how to keep the title of the marker visible after you leave the circle so that multiple markers will have their titles visible at the same time?

Comment: No, what I want is that when my location is within the circle of the marker that is a range of 5 meters, show the name of the marker in which it is, this does but only validates the last marker and does not take into account the others

Comment: So you could be in the circles for multiple markers, and you want to show all of them?

Comment: No, what I want to validate all the bookmarks with my position does not validate me with the last one

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that sentence means.

Comment: I want that if my position is near a marker exaptamente to 5 meters shows the name of the near marker, what happens is that the only valid the last marker not all